# Manifest from library module not merged

Tags: android, module, merge, android-studio, android-library

How can I tell Android Studio to merge the AndroidManifest from my library module with the AndroidManifest of my main module when building?

With aar libraries it works like a charm and all manifest entries get merged, but with modules it seems to not work.

This is the output of the **manifest merger report**

```
manifest
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:2:1
    package
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:3:13
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
    android:versionName
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
    xmlns:android
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:2:11
    android:versionCode
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
application
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:5:5
MERGED from com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3:16:5
MERGED from com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3:16:5
MERGED from MyLib:app:unspecified:11:5
    android:label
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:8:9
    android:allowBackup
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:6:9
    android:icon
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:7:9
    android:theme
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:9:9
activity#com.android.testapplication.TestActivity
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:10:9
    android:label
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:12:13
    android:name
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:11:13
intent-filter#android.intent.action.MAIN+android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:13:13
action#android.intent.action.MAIN
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:14:17
    android:name
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:14:25
category#android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:16:17
    android:name
        ADDED from AndroidManifest.xml:16:27
uses-sdk
INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 reason: use-sdk injection requested
MERGED from com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3:15:5
MERGED from com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3:15:5
MERGED from MyLib:app:unspecified:7:5
    android:targetSdkVersion
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
    android:minSdkVersion
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
        INJECTED from AndroidManifest.xml:0:0
```

Comment: JAR libraries do not have `AndroidManifest.xml` files used by manifest merging, AFAIK. So long as you are on a recent Gradle for Android plugin, manifest merging for AARs and library modules is automatic. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Manifest/Merger) with a library module that demonstrates manifest merging. What specifically is not getting merged in your project?

Comment: Sry, I meant aar files ;) For my case, nothing is merged, clean build hasn´t solved it.

Comment: Does the manifest merger report in `app/build/outputs/apk` give you any clues? The path I cited assumes your app is in a module named `app/`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I´ve checked the file and there seems to be nothing special, except of the "unspecified". But my library manifest has about 170 lines of code and I thing the report has to be much longer then